# GeoServer SQL View with parameter value having space not working

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to make query with GeoServer SQL View. However, GeoServer fails to make a successful query when I use values with spaces.

Below is my setting.

```
SELECT name, orig_name, desig, 
   desig_eng, desig_type, iucn_cat, int_crit, marine, rep_m_area, 
   gis_m_area, rep_area, gis_area, no_take, no_tk_area, status, 
   status_yr, gov_type, own_type, mang_auth, mang_plan, verif, metadataid, 
   sub_loc, parent_iso, iso3, shape_leng, shape_area, geom
FROM public.tz_protected_areas
WHERE desig LIKE %desig%
```

Name: `desig`
Default value: `'Forest Reserve'`
Regex: `^[A-z\s]+$`

Part of my URL with query:

```
application/openlayers&VIEWPARAMS=desig:'Forest%20Reserve'
```

But I get the following error:

```
Invalid value for parameter desig
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value 'Forest plantation' does not match ^[A-z\s]+$
```

**Edit**: I have added the full error message related to the issue below:

```
2017-06-23 19:18:33,859 INFO [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/myws/wms?VIEWPARAMS=desig%3A%27Forest%20Plantation%27&STYLES=&LAYERS=myws%3Atz_protected_areas&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=27.06366873101,-14.292436494419,43.104053958472,1.6644050599834&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=764" took 16ms
2017-06-23 19:18:33,862 INFO [geoserver.filters] - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 "GET /geoserver/myws/wms?VIEWPARAMS=desig%3A%27Forest%20Plantation%27&STYLES=&LAYERS=myws%3Atz_protected_areas&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=27.06366873101,-14.292436494419,43.104053958472,1.6644050599834&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=764" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/myws/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=myws:tz_protected_areas&styles=&bbox=29.7370662689209,-11.62756,40.4306564205623,-1.00047143443565&width=768&height=763&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers&VIEWPARAMS=desig:%27Forest%20Plantation%27" 
2017-06-23 19:18:33,863 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2017-06-23 19:18:33,871 ERROR [geotools.jdbc] - Invalid value for parameter desig
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value 'Forest Plantation' does not match ^[A-z\\]+$
    at org.geotools.jdbc.RegexpValidator.validate(RegexpValidator.java:44)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.VirtualTable.expandParameters(VirtualTable.java:201)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.encodeAliasedTableName(JDBCDataStore.java:4374)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.encodeTableName(JDBCDataStore.java:4363)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.selectSQL(JDBCDataStore.java:3103)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:608)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getReader(ContentFeatureSource.java:563)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:164)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:58)
    at org.geotools.data.crs.ForceCoordinateSystemFeatureResults.openIterator(ForceCoordinateSystemFeatureResults.java:95)
    at org.geotools.feature.collection.AbstractFeatureCollection.features(AbstractFeatureCollection.java:69)
    at org.geotools.feature.collection.AbstractFeatureCollection.features(AbstractFeatureCollection.java:53)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.drawPlain(StreamingRenderer.java:2340)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:2066)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:824)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:515)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:258)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:130)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:510)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:254)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:125)
    at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:369)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor282.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:62)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:36)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.getMap(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor242.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:792)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:274)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am using GeoServer 2.6 and PostgreSQL 9.5 with PostGIS 2.2.
Edit: I also tried GeoServer 2.11 and the issue is the same.

Comment: I'm not sure \s is supported, try using a space or possibly 2 \

Comment: I still get the error when I placed `\\` in place of `\s`.

Comment: There is no need to escape the space

Comment: This editor escaped one of the slashes. :) I mean, when I used \\ it still doesn't work.

Comment: Just a space should work though

Comment: I also tried space but it didn't work.

Comment: Turn logging up to debug and check the log then. May be a bug

Comment: I have added the full error message in the question. Is it sufficient?

Comment: @iant, I also tried GeoServer 2.11 and the issue is the same.

Comment: @wondie I had similar issues, perhaps this thread has a solution https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286717/using-lat-lon-in-leaflet-with-geoserver-geojson

Answer (score 1):

Rather than allow the regex validator to accept anything and everything, add the offending character to the default regex expression which comes with the parameter in Geoserver.

In OP's case, since the offending character is a space, this should work:

`^[\w\d\s\ ]+$`

Answer (score 0):

Try .* for the regexp expression. It's not secure, but it should work.
[image]

Comment: Where do I ad the .*?

Comment: I've just added a screenshot of a parametric view in GeoServer

Comment: Please do not do this, it is extremely insecure and leaves you wide open for SQL injection: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp